# HTML/Javascript-Why I can't use offsetTop for div inside tables ?

Tags: javascript, html

The offsetTop property should return the absolute position of a object. It works nice when I use objects out of tables, but if the object is inside a table it returns always 1. Why it happens and how to avoid it ?

See the problems sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/6Y7qp/

```
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id='a' >a
 <table style='border:solid thin black'>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <div id='b'>b in table</div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <button onclick="document.getElementById('p').innerHTML='offsetTop:\na='+document.getElementById('a').offsetTop+'\nb='+document.getElementById('b').offsetTop">Show Off Set Top</button>
</div>
<pre id='p'>
</pre>
```

In this sample, I need to get "a" and "b" offsetTop, but it always return 1 for "b" in my firefox and chrome browsers

Comment: use element.getBoundingClientRect() for a more comprehensive positioning method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's the way it's supposed to work. As MDN states:

> [offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetTop) returns the distance of the current element relative to
>   the top of the offsetParent node.

What's the offsetParent you say? Glad you asked:

> offsetParent returns a reference to the object which is the closest
>   (nearest in the containment hierarchy) positioned containing element.
>   **If the element is non-positioned, the nearest table cell or root element (html in standards compliant mode; body in quirks rendering
>   mode) is the offsetParent.**

One way around this is to just set a position on the div in the table cell via:

```
td div {
    position:relative;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6Y7qp/2/)**

Comment: ok, so what way i can do to get the absolute position of "b" div in this context ? I mean... there is some other way than scale all parent objects for offsetTop ?

Comment: The second part of my answer should answer that.